# In ReactJS component, when user modifies a cell value, does it modify it in actual DOM or in virtual DOM?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning the ReactJS framework. I'm not clear on below aspect.
When a user enters some value in a form cell, does it modify in actual DOM? or just updates directly first in Virtual DOM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, React has a unidirectional binding, meaning that when you change the state (using `this.setState({...})`), `render()` is called again. This updates the virtual DOM and then updates the actual DOM.

If a user enters input, nothing will happen unless you setup something to change the state on user input (for example, adding `onChange()`). The `onChange` function will then need to update the state with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a value in form cell and there is no input handler for that input field. The actual DOM is getting modified as you are entering the value in a cell and that value will be persisted in the form cell.

But we usually don't do this, instead we will have a `onChange` handler in our component which will take the new value and render back the input cell using `render` method. After render is called, virtual DOM is first updated and then react does its magic of diffing to find out whether the real DOM needs to be updated or not.